# error: "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." when using jquery ajax with Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

in template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url DrHub.views.ajxTest %}",
             data: {
                    'start': $('#id_startTime').val(),
                    'end': $('#id_endTime').val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
             },
             success: function(data){
                 alert(data);
             }
        });
</script>
.
.
.
<form method='POST' action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text id="id_startTime" />
    <input type="text id="id_endTime" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

in views:

```
def ajxTest(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      if request.method == 'POST':
         return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message' : 'awesome'},ensure_ascii=False), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)
```

when submitting form I have this error:`CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

I searched alot but none of suggested solutions worked for me!

like : [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

and : [Ajax Post in Django framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304517/ajax-post-in-django-framework)

I refreenced to a js file with this content:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
     beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
         function getCookie(name) {
             var cookieValue = null;
             if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                 var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                 for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                     var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                     // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                 if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                     cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         return cookieValue;
         }
         if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
             // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
         }
     } 
});
```

but this didn't work,too!

And I saw a solution that say use ajaxSetup instead of ajaxSend to post data,how can I do this?

Comment: have you checked in the firebug that the CSRF token value are being posted

Comment: I don't know how to use firebug :D

Comment: you can get it from here http://getfirebug.com/ its a firefox extension

Comment: I installed firebug but I didn't understand it!

Comment: when your page is loaded press f12 a window will popup infront of you, now inside that window go to `Net` tab and inside that tab select `XHR`, now do the ajax request it will be shown there

Comment: In your browser, do a "view source" on your page and verify that the csrftoken value has been inserted into your javascript.

Comment: @3nigma when I go to Net tab I don't find XHR !!

Comment: @Asma you must be doing something wrong...

Comment: @Asma see here http://i.imgur.com/reo3R.png

Comment: @3nigma I tryed this in a simple form then I checked firebug and I got error "403 forbidden" in jquery.js file in this part:                                                              // Send the data
try {
xhr.send( type === "POST" || type === "PUT" || type === "DELETE" ? s.data : null );
} catch(e) {
jQuery.handleError(s, xhr, null, e);
// Fire the complete handlers
complete();
}
in line XHR.send...

Comment: can you check what parameters were sent in the request, check the params tab when you click on the error message

Comment: I don't have params tab!!!! but at Post tab I can see my parameters just when I give fixed value to theme,like: start: "8",
     end: "12",
     csrfmiddlewaretoken:"SDSDSFSF"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

having this a refrence to a js file with this content was my solution:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    function safeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should pull the csrfmiddlewaretoken from the dom element:

`{'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$( "#csrfmiddlewaretoken" ).val()}`

The above is exactly what I do in several places and it works.

Edit just to add some clarity drawing from your material:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"{% url DrHub.views.ajxTest %}",
         data: {
                'start': $('#id_startTime').val(),
                'end': $('#id_endTime').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$( "#csrfmiddlewaretoken" ).val()
         },
         success: function(data){
             alert(data);
         }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding this: 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware', directly below 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

Comment: adding this line cause this error:A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

Comment: what version of django are you using?

Comment: django is 1.3,what do U think?

Comment: My version of django (1.7) doesn't give the hidden element an id, so `#csrf...` won't work. Instead I needed to get the element using a name selector: `$('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()`.

Answer (score 4):

There's also another shortcut to this. I wouldn't know if the security thing here is of so much value and importance. I ran into this problem but there seems to be a lot of hacks around this that end up trying to submit the csrftoken from an existing cookie. I don't know what would happen if this cookie does not exist or was not set.

My approach was to add a `@csrf_exempt` to the view that processes the ajax post.
You import the `csrf_exempt` from `django.views.decorators.csrf`

Like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

And than, from the view method:

```
@csrf_exempt
def the_method_to_be_called(request):
```

...

see [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views)

Answer (score 1):

in HTML(template)

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

in JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/brand-admin/publish_article/',
    data: {
      'article_id': article_id,
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$( "input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']" ).val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solve it by doing following:

```
let data = {};
data.somedata = somedata;
data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';

  $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/myadmin/user/medical/"+rowId,
          data: data,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
        });
```

Hope this will work for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the csrfmiddlewaretoken as `csrfmiddlewaretoken`: 
`{% csrf_token %}` in your js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url DrHub.views.ajxTest %}",
             data: {
                    'start': $('#id_startTime').val(),
                    'end': $('#id_endTime').val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{% csrf_token %}'
             },
             success: function(data){
                 alert(data);
             }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `{% csrf_token %}` is in your form on your template:

```
<form id="the-form" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

you should be able to send it up using:

```
$("#the-form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/post-url",
    data: $("#the-form").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLEST WAY:
`csrfmiddlewaretoken` will be available in dom elements.

Just fetch the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` from the dom elements using the name as shown below:

```
'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
```

You can fetch it by id also, but sometimes that dom element won't be carrieng id, So this is the best way.

You can just copy paste the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"{% url DrHub.views.ajxTest %}",
        data: {
                'start': $('#id_startTime').val(),
                'end': $('#id_endTime').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```