# Uncaught TypeError: Has no method ajaxSend when sending AJAX from Django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am using a function called $.ajaxSend instead of $.ajax to send AJAX post requests. When I just add the ajaxSend function to the bottom of the JS file, I get a 403 forbidden when I try to do post requests on the remote machine, but the local machine works. Here is the error I get when I try to do an AJAX post call:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'ajaxSend'
```

Here is what the script looks like:

```
        $.ajax({
           ... do post stuff ...
        });

$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    function safeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

I got the code from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

I tried following these instructions but they didn't work:
[error: "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." when using jquery ajax with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383221/error-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-when-using-jquery-ajax-with)

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.7.1 found here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

The `.ajaxSend` has to be attached to a jQuery object (like in Django example: to the `$(document)` object, not `$` itself). This function **is not** for doing AJAX, but for setting AJAX before it fires. So you should use `$.ajax({...});` in the first line (the Django code is fine). See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) for details.

The real question is: how can this code work locally? :)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use it. I am still confused. Thanks.

Comment: When I just add the ajaxSend function to the bottom of the JS file, I get a 403 forbidden when I try to do post requests on the remote machine, but the local machine works.

Comment: try putting `$(document).ajaxSend` at the begining and use use `$.ajax` call inside `$(document).ready(function(){ $.ajax({ ... }); });`.